# Change tesseract dependency version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tesseract, libjpeg

how to change version of `libjpeg` tesseract's dependency?
Currently tesseract uses `libjpeg 6b` but I need `libjpeg 8d`. I've tried to install `libjpeg8` by `apt-get install`, library is installs but dependency version is not change. Also I've tried to install `libjpeg 8d` from [here](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs-museum/snapshot-20121101/blfs-20121102/general/libjpeg.html) but result the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tesseract does not have libjepg as dependency. teserract use leptonica for accessing image input.
So you need to install libjpeg-dev with correct version and rebuild leptonica from source.